# Contour integral over a small disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C_p$ be the set of all complex numbers of modulus $p$, $0<p<1$, oriented in the clockwise direction. Suppose $f(z)$ is continuous on the open unit disk. Show that:

$\lim_{p \to 0} \int_{C_p}$ ${f(z)}\over{(z^{1/2})}$$dz$ $=0$

along the principal branch.

This seems obvious, and I know I need to bound the absolute value of the integral and use that $|z|<p$ but I am not sure how.

Comment: sorry! It was 0.

Comment: Standard estimate. The absolute value of the integral is not larger than the maximum of the absolute value of the integrand times the length of the path.

Comment: Yes, but what is the absolute value of the integrand?

Comment: Some constant that you get from the continuity of $f$, divided by $\sqrt{p}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is supposed to be continuous on the unit disk, it is bounded on the closed disk of radius $1/2$, which is compact,

$$(\exists K > 0) \left(\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \frac12 \Rightarrow \lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant K\right).$$

Thus the standard estimate yields, for $p < \frac12$,

$$\left\lvert \int_{C_p} \frac{f(z)}{\sqrt{z}}\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant 2\pi p \cdot \frac{K}{\sqrt{p}} = 2\pi K \sqrt{p},$$

and that clearly tends to $0$ for $p\to 0$.